ConcurrentHashMap$Node accumulate in heap without clean by GC
I am using ConcurrentHashMap to cache some short-lived data. That is, there are not many entries in the cache, but insertion and deletion often occur. The problem is that when working under load, GC does not delete java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node and they accumulate in heap. Even after the end of the load, they are not cleaned.
My singleton cache-manager
@Component
public class ZipkinTraceCacheManager {

    private final Map<String, ZipkinTraceCache> threadCaches = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public ZipkinTraceCache getCache(String mainSpanId) {
        return threadCaches.get(mainSpanId);
    }

    public void removeCache(String mainSpanId) {
        threadCaches.remove(mainSpanId);
    }

    public String initNewCache(Span mainSpan) {

        ZipkinTraceCache zipkinTraceCache = new ZipkinTraceCache();
        zipkinTraceCache.setMainSpan(mainSpan);

        String mainSpanId = mainSpan.context().spanId();

        threadCaches.put(mainSpanId, zipkinTraceCache);

        return mainSpanId;
    }
}

As u can see on graph, the minimal value of used heap is growing

After working under load ended, all java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node instances still alive

What I need to do to stop accumulating these references?

The problem was in custom Apache Camel component

Are you using Spring or spring-boot? @Component has default scope of singleton which mean that:-
When the Spring IoC container is started, it creates an instance of the singleton bean and this instance lives for the entire lifetime of the application context. Therefore, any class variables (like threadCaches in your example) are also instantiated and live for the entire lifetime of the application context. The garbage collection of the threadCaches will occur when the singleton bean that contains it is eligible for garbage collection.   This typically happens when the application context is closed or the entire application is shutdown, and there are no other references to the singleton bean.

You've come up with a good idea. It is SpringBoot Component.
But I need a ZipkinTraceCacheManager  where the cache is stored, as a @Component, so that there is a singleton for each instance of the class that uses it. What should be done in this case?

1. Check for Strong References
The ConcurrentHashMap uses strong references for keys and values. If your mainSpanId (key) or zipkinTraceCache (value) objects are being held onto by other parts of your application even after removal from the cache, they will not be garbage collected.
Ensure that objects associated with mainSpanId and zipkinTraceCache are not referenced elsewhere in your application once removed from the cache.
2. Consider Weak References
Instead of using a ConcurrentHashMap with strong references, you might consider using WeakHashMap or SoftHashMap from libraries like Guava. These maps use weak or soft references for keys, allowing entries to be garbage collected when there are no strong references to the keys.
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
public class ZipkinTraceCacheManager {
private final Map<String, ZipkinTraceCache> threadCaches = new WeakHashMap<>();

public ZipkinTraceCache getCache(String mainSpanId) {
    return threadCaches.get(mainSpanId);
}

public void removeCache(String mainSpanId) {
    threadCaches.remove(mainSpanId);
}

public String initNewCache(Span mainSpan) {
    ZipkinTraceCache zipkinTraceCache = new ZipkinTraceCache();
    zipkinTraceCache.setMainSpan(mainSpan);

    String mainSpanId = mainSpan.context().spanId();

    threadCaches.put(mainSpanId, zipkinTraceCache);

    return mainSpanId;
}

}
3. Check Cache Expiry Mechanism
Ensure that the short-lived nature of the cached data is reflected in your cache management logic. If entries should expire after a certain period of time or based on some conditions, implement a cleanup mechanism to remove expired entries periodically.
